# Stack divs with different heights

Tags: html, layer

I want to stack divs with different heights but same width within a div container.. from top to bottom going right.

Problem now is with divs that are short.. gives a ugly gap to the div above.

I've added a small sketch with what i want to do..
[image]

Thanks from norway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that you are using jQuery on your site. From the sketch I suggest to take a look at jQuery plugin called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html).

Comment: Bakudan: I can just say WOW! This is the stuff i've been looking for! Perfect, specially the image solution at http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/images.html. Big thanks! This is why i love stackoverflow :) Beautiful solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**CSS:**

```
.column { width:20em; float:left }
.column div { background:red; margin:1em }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using CSS Columns

Here's the [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), but a slightly easier read might be [PPK's write up](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use three column divs within container div. Each floats left.
Add a div at the top and at the bottom that's empty and clears on both sides.

.column {
float: left;
width: whatever you want it to be;
margin-left:  whatever you want it to be;
}

.clear{
clear: both;
height: 0px;
}

.column div{
margin-bottom: whatever you want it to be;
width: whatever you want it to be;
}

```
       <div id='container'>

<div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>

  <div class='column'>
<div>blah blah blah</div><div>blah blah blah</div>... etc
  </div>

  <div class='column'>
 <div>blah blah blah</div><div>blah blah blah</div>... etc
   </div>

  <div class='column'>
<div>blah blah blah</div><div>blah blah blah</div>... etc
  </div>

<div class='clear'>&nbsp;</div>

       </div>
```