# Bootstrap: how to stack divs of different heights?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This question is a bit similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131661/stack-divs-with-different-heights), but I want to know if there is a pure CSS solution that is compatible with Bootstrap.

Basically, I have the following layout:

[image]

This is the HTML of that page:

```
<div class="menu row">
    <div class="menu-category list-group col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="menu-category-name list-group-item active">Category</div><a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-category list-group col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="menu-category-name list-group-item active">Category</div><a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-category list-group col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="menu-category-name list-group-item active">Category</div><a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-category list-group col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="menu-category-name list-group-item active">Category</div><a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-category list-group col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="menu-category-name list-group-item active">Category</div><a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="menu-item list-group-item">Lorem ipsum.<span class="badge">€ 0.00</span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, as you can see, that the row system of Bootstrap is a bit inconvenient here. I want these categories to stack in the most optimal way. 
So my question is: how can I do that with CSS? The masonry plugin seems excellent but I would like to keep it for plan B.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Take a look at these examples..

[Masonry-style Layout ONLY with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117195/masonry-style-layout-only-with-css)

Applied to your Bootstrap `list-group` it would look something like this..

http://bootply.com/85737

However, you need to remove the Bootstrap `col-*` classes from your markup since they use floats a mess up the masonry layout. Use the `*-column-width` property to change the width of the panels. So, it's possible with pure CSS, but not cross-browser compatible so you still may want to use the [Masonry plugin](http://www.codeply.com/go/RIbbf5pk8k) as a fallback.

If you're simply looking to ensure the columns wrap every *x* columns, use Bootstrap [responsive resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets), or a clearfix solution with media queries like this: http://www.codeply.com/go/jXuoGHHker

[**More on solving the different heights issue**](https://medium.com/wdstack/varying-column-heights-in-bootstrap-4e8dd5338643)

**UPDATE** Bootstrap 4 will include a [CSS column layout masonry option](https://www.codeply.com/go/q03ZHDeSGN).

Comment: This is great! I'm in the luxurious position of only having to support modern browsers, so I'll go for the column css solution. Thanks for writing it out, this was new to me.

Comment: @IanSteffy you should delete that comment. that link has been OBE for a very long time

Answer (score 33):

Better to use .visible-sm,.visible-md, .visible-lg with clearfix classes. That helps to clear the floats according to screen sizes also.

```
<!-- This will clear the float in Middle and Large Size screens only -->
<div class="clearfix visible-md visible-lg"></div>

<!-- This will clear the float in Small Size screens only -->
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
```

[See Reference: on Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: Great solution! Clean and helpful!

Comment: This does help the rows to wrap every X, but doesn't eliminate spacing like a "masonry" style layout. Also, it's a lot more markup: http://www.codeply.com/go/3gS13OJmea

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="sub-grid">....</div>
    <div class="sub-grid">....</div>
    <div class="sub-grid">....</div>
</div>


.grid-container{


   -moz-column-count:2;
   -moz-column-gap:10px;
   -webkit-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-gap:10px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;

}
.sub-grid{display: inline-block;width: 100%;}
```

demo http://teknosains.com/

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on the answer of @ashish-kumar

I have items shaped as a box, as follows

```
<div class="row the-list">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box">...</div>
</div>
```

The trick is to add a clearfix div, after every ".box" item, like so

```
<div class="row the-list">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box">...</div>
    <div class="box-wrap clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box">...</div>
    <div class="box-wrap clearfix"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 box">...</div>
    <div class="box-wrap clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

This can be achieved using jQuery

```
$('<div class="box-wrap clearfix"></div>').insertAfter('.box');
```

Now, using css, I've made the ".clearfix" of after every 2nd\3rd\4th box (depending on the current screen size), be shown.

```
/* hide all new lines by default */
.the-list .box-wrap {
    display: none;
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* reset new lines */
    .row.the-list .box-wrap {
        display: none;
    }
    /* new line every 2nd box */
    .the-list .box-wrap:nth-child(4n) {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    /* reset new lines */
    .row.the-list .box-wrap {
        display: none;
    }
    /* new line every 3rd box */
    .the-list .box-wrap:nth-child(6n) {
        display: block;
    }

}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    /* reset new lines */
    .row.the-list .box-wrap {
        display: none;
    }
    /* new line every 4th box */
    .the-list .box-wrap:nth-child(8n) {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Notice that when doing the "reset new lines", the rule is `.row.the-list .box-wrap` and has the ".row" at the beginning, so that this rule [will precede](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) the `display: block;` of the rules before it.

A live example, see [All Escape Rooms UK](http://allescaperooms.co.uk)'s website