# Bootstrap Fluid grid system with different height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new in Bootstrap. I want to use the fluid grid system grid with different height and same width like the following image [image: Bootstrap grid image].

How can i implement the same? Please help me.

Comment: Not related to PHP. And you could just use [one the of examples from the Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to do so. Each column may contain elements with different heights – which is the default. In contrary it is a bit more complex to get equal height columns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: how to stack divs of different heights?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196082/bootstrap-how-to-stack-divs-of-different-heights)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The only way to do this with Bootstrap "out-of-the-box" would be to use 4 columns and stack the items in each. This isn't ideal for dynamic content when you don't know how many items you'll have in each column. Also the items order *top-to-bottom,* and not *left-to-right*.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <!--item1-->
        <!--item2-->
        <!--item3-->
        <!--item4-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <!--item5-->
        <!--item6-->
        <!--item7-->
        <!--item8-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <!--item-->
        <!--item-->
        <!--item-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <!--item-->
        <!--item-->
        <!--item-->
        <!--item-->
        <!--item-->
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

---

Otherwise, you have to use a jQuery plugin like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), or using CSS3 multi-columns.

**Jquery plugin method**

[Bootstrap Masonry Demo](http://www.bootply.com/108697)
[Bootstrap Masonry Demo 2](http://www.codeply.com/go/UYk8DzIDv6)

**CSS3 columns method (Masonry-like CSS solution)..**

This is not native to Bootstrap 3, but another approach using [CSS multi-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts). One downside to this approach is the column order is *top-to-bottom* instead of *left-to-right*.

[CSS3 multi-columns Demo](http://www.bootply.com/120682)

There is also [more detailed info in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196082/bootstrap-how-to-stack-divs-of-different-heights/19196388#19196388) to a similar question.

### Update 2018

**Bootstrap 4** includes a Masonry-like solution using CSS3 multi-columns:
[Masonry cards Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/q03ZHDeSGN)

Answer (score 10):

**Bootstrap** `v4.0.0-beta.2` **Card columns**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0 card-body">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small>
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" src="..." alt="Card image">
  </div>
  <div class="card p-3 text-right">
    <blockquote class="blockquote mb-0">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
      <footer class="blockquote-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">
          Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
        </small>
      </footer>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can learn  more about it  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/

Comment: much better approach :)

Answer (score 4):

*As of bootstrap 4 alpha release:*

You can also use the `.card-columns` class to wrap your bootstrap 4 `.cards` class elements to achieve the 'Masonry' column effect @Skelly mentioned:

documentation: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#columns

Answer (score 1):

Copy this to sample  body on your html as seeing this easier to understand than explaining.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px; background-color:red"></div>    
                <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px; background-color:yellow"></div>
                <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px; background-color:gray"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" style="height:200px; background-color:blue"></div>       
                <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px; background-color:black"></div>
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As i can see you have fixed width at you columns.
So you can write

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
  boxes
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
 boxes
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
boxes
</div>
```