# HTML + CSS: Card layout that doesn't clear all items in previous row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid layout using Bootstrap where each `div` has a different height.  Once I overflow onto the next row, I'd like my `div`s to tessellate rather than clearing the tallest item from the previous row.  In my [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jK1Yr84Gt4), you can see the div on the second row clears the last items height in the first row.

**I'd like that div to move up, directly under the first item in the first row**

Comment: are you looking for a masonry efffect? please clarify

Comment: take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244268/bootstrap-fluid-grid-system-with-different-height/19244925

Comment: I've looked through masonry but I need mine to be responsive and have the ability to change the number of columns based on screen width

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/19244268 I was able to make the masonry plug in respond to screen width by adding media queries for their `.grid-sizer` element:

```
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) { 
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 50%; 
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 33%; 
    } 
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 25%; 
    } 
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) { 
    .grid-sizer,
    .grid-item {
        width: 20%; 
    } 
}
```