# Bootstrap 3 - Fit on space created between columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 3 col-md-6 columns, the third one is meant to be the the bottom.However, Since the 2nd column is the longest of the three, it created a gap between the first and the third, in which I want to avoid by moving the 3rd to fill the gap.
Is there a bootstrap class for this?

Anyway, an illustration below explains it better.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Fluid grid system with different height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19244268/bootstrap-fluid-grid-system-with-different-height)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `row-eq-ht` class to the `<div class="row">...<div>` as `<div class="row row-eq-ht">`

```
.row-eq-ht {
 display: flex;
}
```