# Left align div using bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following divs that i am trying to align in a certain order. I would like to have them form two rows, with divs aligned to left always.

I have the code of the same here: [Code on Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nas4MSwviK7esUU97S2F?p=info)

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <table class="table">
        <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="info"><td><b>I have to be left aligned</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Live preview of the same is here: [Live preview](http://run.plnkr.co/maWLg7NQ7vbGkRyS/)

What can I do to left align the fourth div.

Comment: Might wanna take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196082/bootstrap-how-to-stack-divs-of-different-heights

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the first three columns in a `row` and then the last column in another `row`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <table class="table">
            <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <table class="table">
            <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <table class="table">
            <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="float:left;">
        <table class="table">
            <tr class="info"><td><b>I have to be left aligned</b></td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td>item</td></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8SSAsT76bHNdSvThhl0v?p=preview

Comment: Plain and simple. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Have a further look to bootstrap's grid. Containers, rows and columns. You will find it really useful for the future!

Comment: That works but mobile view is still not working as expected. When mobile view is using 'col-sm-*' the third div and fourth div get stacked up instead of getting aligned side by side.

Comment: found a solution to the problem. Added the same here.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following code.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <table class="table">
        <tr class="info"><td><b>Row 1</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="info"><td><b>I have to be left aligned</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here i am using bootstraps's clear fix selectively to get 'Responsive column resets'. More here [Responsive column resets](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)